# On the structure of commutative group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes, algebraic-groups

The structure of a commutative affine algebraic group $G$ over a field $k$ is understood (SGA 3): $G$ has a maximal subgroup of multiplicative type $M$ and the quotient $G/M$ is unipotent.

I am looking for any generalization of this structure theory for commutative group schemes over an integral base scheme, $X$. I'd appreciate any general comments/references but for sake of an explicit question:

By a unipotent group scheme I mean a group scheme over $X$ that has a normal series with $\mathbb G_a$-factors. Then the question is: let $G$ be a smooth commutative group scheme of finite type $G$ over an integral $\mathbb C$-scheme $X$ admitting a maximal torus $T$. Does there exist a Zariski open $U \subset X$ over which $G/T$ is unipotent in this sense?

Comment: Dear Pooya, It might help to clarify exactly what you mean by "maximal torus" in the relative context.  Regards,

Comment: Are there smooth commutative unipotent groups that are not vector spaces?

Comment: Dear Emerton: yes! A maximal torus is a subgroup scheme $T$ of $G$ which is a torus (i.e. fpqc locally isomorphic to $\mathbb G_m^r$) and point-wise maximal: for any point $x \in X$, $T_{\bar x}$ is the maximal torus of $G_{\bar x}$ where $\bar x$ is the spectrum of the algebraic closure of $\kappa (x)$ [SGA 3-IIX, Definition 1.3]. Thanks, 

Comment: Dear Will: I think they are vector spaces (i.e. Zariski locally trivial) by my definition [Kambayashi-Miyanishi, on flat fibrations by the affine line]. 

Comment: The quotient $G/T$ exists as a smooth affine group, and by design it is unipotent on geometric fibers over the integral base in char. 0. The generic fiber is unipotent over the char. 0 function field of the base. Your definition of unipotence is wrong in char. $> 0$ (where there are many smooth connected commutative unipotent groups containing no $\mathbf{G}_a$), but in char. 0 it is equivalent to the "right" definition (the filtration condition on geometric fibers).  Such a composition series on the actual (not just geometric) generic fiber spreads out over some dense open of the base.

Comment: Dear grp: so is it the case that if $G$ is a group scheme over base scheme $X$ with generic point $\eta$, and $G_\eta$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb G_{a, \eta}$ then $G$ has a subgroup scheme isomorphic to $\mathbb G_{a,X}$ pulling back to the former one? why?

Comment: @Pooya: No, not over the entirety of $X$.  For example the underlying additive group of a line bundle with no nonzero global section is a counterexample to the global statement.  But in your question you only asked for the property over some (dense) open subset of the base, and that much follows from standard "spreading out" arguments.  

Comment: Yes sorry grp, I rather meant on an open subset too. I guess my question is becoming naive then? I understand that one can spread out certain "properties" of morphisms but why should a morphism $\mathbb G_{a, U} \to G_U$ for an open $U$ exist at the first place (pulling back to the one on the generic fiber)?

Comment: @Pooya: Consider two affine finite type $X$-groups $G$ and $H$ (e.g., $H$ could be $\mathbf{G}_a$).  By general spreading-out principles, any $\eta$-scheme map $H_{\eta} \rightarrow G_{\eta}$ spreads out to a $U$-scheme morphism $H_U \rightarrow G_U$ for some dense open $U$ in $X$.  If the given $\eta$-map is a homomorphism (resp. closed immersion) then we can arrange the same for the $U$-map by shrinking $U$ a bit.  Here we use that "homomorphism" amounts to a commutative diagram (i.e., an equality of some maps) and "closed immersion" is one of those properties which can be "spread out".

Comment: @Will: Witt vectors of length $n>1$ form counterexamples in positive characteristic.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: True, but Witt groups are nonetheless "split" (in the sense that they have a composition series over $k$ with successive quotients $k$-isomorphic to $\mathbf{G}_a$), so a more striking kind of example answering Will's question in the negative is one which doesn't even contain $\mathbf{G}_a$ as a $k$-subgroup. Of course there are no such examples when $k$ is perfect, but for imperfect $k$ Rosenlicht gave the classic example $y^p = x - a x^p$ for $a \in k - k^p$ with any $p = {\rm{char}}(k) > 0$. Tits studied this phenomenon in detail (in any dimension) in his Yale lecture notes.